# Is there any way to prevent Windows from opening exe files without double checking?

Tags: windows

Not talking about specifically UAC which asks when elevation is required, I am talking about any exe file.

I am asking this since there are malware which try to hide their extension in various ways, and there is a possibility of accidentally running them.

Comment: Such files should be caught by your anti-virus software. Which one to use is of-topic on [su].

Comment: Mmm, antiviruses are pretty meh in general, and give many false positive as well as miss a lot of stuff. They only provide surface level defense against common threats.

Answer (score 1):

Impossible - Windows itself launches many programs as it is doing its jobs.

Such a change would basically cause Windows to become unusable.

You should really trust your anti-virus. Windows Defender is an excellent
product, but third-party products do exist. If worried, run a deep
antivirus scan of your computer from time to time.

Comment: Obviously I am not talking about Windows itself being unable to launch any exe. I am talking about user-action launching of exe files. Just like Windows doesn't spam me with UAC prompts  upon its boot even though it runs quite a few stuff with admin privileges. That aside, antiviruses are actually pretty meh, and you shouldn't trust them. It's theoretically impossible for an antivirus to detect all malicious software, all it does is have a list of common things and detect those (false alarms as well no alarms are pretty common).

Comment: That's not all - runtime protection actually detects suspicious behavior of programs, pattern-matching is far from being the whole story. Executable files are also flagged when they use dangerous API functions, etc. A good antivirus does a lot, much more than you can do. What facts will you use for judging an executable's right to execute, and how will you do better than the antivirus that considers dozens of factors?

Comment: It basically comes down to pattern matching, even the stuff you said like using "dangerous" API functions is basically  pattern matching. The antivirus does not know your intention, so it cannot tell whether the software is doing what you intend it to do or not, that's why it's impossible for it to block a lot of stuff. For example consider something I observed recently, which is the recent surge of executables that steal your Discord app token, I've seen a lot have their token stolen, presumably most of them using Windows defender.

Comment: Technically, if you want to execute an untrusted executable sandboxing it is the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, but it's far from being only pattern matching. If you are worried, my own solution is to execute unknown files using [Sandboxie](https://sandboxie-plus.com/Sandboxie/) which isolates them from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You COULD block EXE (& other file types) in certain locations with [Group Policy 'Software Restriction Policies'](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/software-restriction-policies/software-restriction-policies). [AppLocker](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview) is its replacement, but only available in Enterprise version of Windows. Its fairly complicated, but WAS used to control Ransomware early on before the antivirus companies got a better control of it.